# Revising JS code to import ES module to fix error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript

[This code](https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/dyGPRVj) works fine, using version 3.0.3 of an external library:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@3.0.3/dist/index.min.js"></script>

<button id="emoji-button">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
const button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');

const picker = new EmojiButton();
picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
    document.querySelector('#input').value += emoji;
});
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
picker.togglePicker(button);
});
```

The new version of the library (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@4.0.1/dist/index.min.js) no longer works - as I get an error in the JS:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/joeattardi/emoji-button/issues/77), and the developer confirmed:

> As of version 4, Emoji Button is exported as an ES module only

The person who raised the issue said:

**I found a workaround by using the browser modules functionality:**

```
<script type='module' src="/js/emoji.js"></script>
import { EmojiButton } from '/js/vendor/emojibutton.min.js'
```

Unfortunately I am not clear how to adjust the code that works for 3.0.3 to work for version 4+.

I tried changing this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@3.0.3/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@4.0.1/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

But from there - how do I edit my 3.0.3 code to include the import section mentioned in the workaround?

Comment: The same person who opened that issue, also suggested a [workaround](https://github.com/joeattardi/emoji-button/issues/77#issuecomment-663289120)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `import` inside your javascript file, where you use the export. And you can remove the script tag from your HTML.

```js
import {EmojiButton} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@4.0.1/dist/index.min.js';

const button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');

const picker = new EmojiButton();
picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
    document.querySelector('#input').value += emoji;
  });
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  picker.togglePicker(button);
});
```